# regex - How to match a substring after X occurrences of a pattern?

Tags: regex, go

```
ab1-cde23-fg45-h6-ijk-789.lmn.local.        86400 IN A  12.34.5.123
```

In the follow DNS entry, I'm trying to match the `h6` section (position 4). At this point, I know this section of the domain is only composed of 2 letters/digits or one of each, so I can match it (in a clumsy way) with

```
"-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-"
```

**In a case where I could not assume that this is the only section of a domain with 2 letters/digits, how could I match only the content of the 4th position minus the `-`?** (`ab1` being the first position, `cde23` the second, and so on, with all the positions separated by `-`)

I'm able to match up to the 4th positions with the following regex, but it includes everything from the start.

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9]*-){3}[a-zA-Z0-9]*-"
```

I'm using theses regexp in golang.

Comment: Is regex required? Why not split and then select the 4th element from the array?

Comment: I could have indeed done it by splitting the string, but I was curious to see how that could be achieved with regex :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do:

```
^(?:[^-]+-){3}([^-]+)
```

- `^(?:[^-]+-){3}` matches `-` separated first 3 fields, `(?:)` makes the group non-capturing
- The captured group, `([^-]+)`  will contain the `-` separated 4th field.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OnkEJA/1)

---

While we are at this, you should perhaps look at string manipulation rather than costly Regex implementation, plain `strings.Split()` should do:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "ab1-cde23-fg45-h6-ijk-789.lmn.local.        86400 IN A  12.34.5.123"
    fmt.Println(strings.Split(s, "-")[3])
}
```

Comment: That worked! I had some troubles with groups, that helped me to understand way better!

Comment: @Cocotton Great. Check my edits too; i think string manipulation is what you should be after in this case.

Comment: Yes that would work well indeed! But I'll admit I thought regex would be faster than straight string manipulations. Very interesting, thanks!